# Prevent Laravel factory to create linked model entries

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I am new to Laravel and here is my setup:

- I have a `companies` table which is linked to a `plans` table (`plan_id`)
- I have a function that seed the `plans` table with very specific data
- I have created a factory for the `Company` model but not for the `Plan` model as I don't want random data for this model (I have 3 plans with prices)

**My issue is that when I run the `Company` factory, it creates new `Plan` entries instead of using the existing ones.**

Here is my `DatabaseSeeder`:

```
/**
 * Seed the application's database.
 */
public function run(): void
{
    // Create the plans.
    $this->createPlans();

    Company::factory()
        ->count(3)
        ->create();
}

/**
 * Create the plans.
 *
 * @return void
 */
private function createPlans(): void
{
    Plan::create([
        'name' => __('Free'),
        'amount' => 0.00,
    ]);

    Plan::create([
        'name' => __('Pro'),
        'amount' => 99.95,
    ]);

    Plan::create([
        'name' => __('Business'),
        'amount' => 199.95,
    ]);
}
```

And my `CompanyFactory`:

```
public function definition(): array
{
    return [
        'plan_id' => fake()->randomElement(Plan::all()->pluck('id')->toArray()),
        'name' => fake()->company(),
        'plan_status' => fake()->randomElement(['active', 'pending', 'canceled']),
    ];
}
```

Each time I seed the database, it creates x new entries for the plans instead of using existing entries. I have tried many things, but I can't get it to work... Could somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Try to pass the plan_id to the factory  like this Company::factory()
        ->count(3)
        ->create(['plan_id' => 1]);
if this work for you then save the generated plan ids and choose one randomly if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have found my issue. I was running the `db:seed --class=DatabaseSeeder` command so it makes sense that it creates everytime 3 new entries as this what I've written... So I have created a custom `PlanSeeder` to isolate the `Plan` creation and it now works perfectly!

Thanks to everyone who took the time to answer :).

Answer (score 0):

You could manually select a plan_id from the existing plans without using the fake() function.

```
$existingPlanIds = Plan::pluck('id')->toArray();

return [
    'plan_id' => $this->faker->randomElement($existingPlanIds),
    'name' => $this->faker->company(),
    'plan_status' => $this->faker->randomElement(['active', 'pending', 'canceled']),
];
```